# Making text and navbar fixed vertically and relative horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Working on the site www.bedriftsdesign.no I made both the navigation and the #landing-text (on top of the header image fixed.

When I changed their position to fixed though something else happened. Although they'll stay fixed when scrolling vertically, if you scroll horizontally (especially on a small screen) they won't stick to their place.

So my question is, can I make something fixed (vertically) and relative (horizontally)? If so, how?

Here's an example of a site where it works, and approximately what I'm trying to get: www.googleventures.com

Thanks

Comment: In which browser is this? When I test it in Chrome it works exactly as the example site.

Comment: I might not have explained it well enough. Try making your browser window smaller in chrome, so you get a horizontal scrollbar. Two things happen: The text on top of the header starts scrolling (not the social bar on top which I haven't fixed).

Also I just noticed that if I decrease the broswser window size the header image scales, leaving a grey background color between the header and the content.

Compare that too the how the example site handles scaling... thats what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for taking a look. I'm still learning =)